# Login as SYS user to Oracle 11g from .NET

Tags: .net, oracle, oracle11g, connect, sysdba

Using the Oracle Data Provider for .NET, my application connects to the database using the privileged SYS user. The connection string is as follows:

```
Data Source=MyTnsName;User ID=sys;Password=MySysPassword;DBA Privilege=SYSDBA
```

This works fine with Oracle 10, but Oracle 11 keeps complaining about an invalid username or password. I verified that the password is correct - other apps work fine with the same credentials.

Note that for regular users (without the `DBA Privilege` part), connecting to Oracle 11 works perfectly.

So, what's wrong?

> **Update**:
>   This is not an issue with case sensitivity - when constructing the connection string, the password case is not altered by my code, and the password works fine with other, non-.NET-applications.
>
> I suspect that this might be caused by the Oracle 10 client I'm using to connect to the 11 database. Oracle states that the client is upward-compatible, the only drawback being that you cannot use some new features of the database. However, `SYSDBA` connections clearly are not a new Oracle 11 feature, and - again - a non-.NET-app (Keeptool Hora) can connect using the same setup.
>
> Any other ideas?

> **Update 2:**
>   The problem persists when using an Oracle 11 client :-(

> **Update 3:**
>   I made a test with another database installation, version 11.2 (first was 11.1) - same result.
>
> Also, it might be worth noting that with the user `SYSTEM` (also using the `DBA Privilege` part), everything works fine. However, I *have* to work with `SYS`.

Answer (score 0):

One thing which changed in 11g is that passwords became case sensitive.  I don't know how you're making your ConnectionString, but could it be getting (or putting) the password in the wrong case?

Comment: No, that is not the problem here! The connection string is put together with simple concatenation; I checked that there are no case alterations anywhere in my code, and the credentials themselves work in other applications (which are not .NET-based).

Answer (score -1):

According to [this thread](http://dbaforums.org/oracle/index.php?s=71996c686c22cbced7055e2e141277cd&showtopic=8148)  you must add `as sysdba` to your connectionstring.

Comment: That connection string applies to "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle", I am using "Oracle Data Provider for .NET".